# Developer2000 OPEN_FORM built-in

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I am a newbie in Developer2000.
I have an Oracle pl/sql procedure (say, proc_submit_request) that fetches thousands of requests and submits them to dbms_job scheduler. The calling of dbms_job is

coded inside a loop for each request fetched.

Currently, i have a button (say, SUBMIT button) in oracle forms screen clicking which calls proc_submit_request.
The problem here is... the control does not return to my screen untill ALL of the requests fetched are submitted to the dbms_job (this takes hours to complete)
The screen grays out and just the hour-glass appears untill the completion of the procedure proc_submit_request.
proc_submit_appears returns a message to screen telling "XXXX requests submitted".

My requirement now is, once the user clicks the SUBMIT button, the screen should no longer gray out. The user should be able to navigate to other screens and not just struck with the submit screen untill the called procedure is completed.

I suggested running listeners (shell scripts and perl stuff) that can listen for any messages in pipe and run requests as back-ground process.
But the user is asking me to fix the issue in the application rather running listeners.

I've heard a little of OPEN_FORM built-in.
Suppose, I have two forms namely Form-1 and Form-2. Form-1 calls Form-2 using OPEN_FORM. 
Now are the following things possible using OPEN_FORM?

1. On calling open_form('Form-2',OTHER-ARGUMENTS...), control must be in Form-1 (i.e. USer should not know that another form is getting opened) and Form-2 should call proc_submit_request.
2. User must be able to navigate to other screens in the application. But Form-2 must still be running until proc_submit_procedure is completed.
3. What happens if the user closes (exits) Form-1 ?  Will Form-2 be still running?

Please provide me answers or suggest a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Good thought on the Form-1, Form-2 scenario - I'm not sure if that would work or not.  But here is a much easier way without having to fumble around with coordinating forms being hidden and running stuff, and coming to the forefront when the function actually returns...etc, etc.

Rewrite your function that runs the database jobs to run as an `AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION`.  Have a look at the compiler directive `PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION` for more details on that.  You must use this within a database function/package/procedure - it is not valid with Forms (at least forms 10, not sure about 11).

You can then store the jobs result somewhere from your function (package variable, table, etc) and then use the built-in called `CREATE_TIMER` in conjunction with the form level trigger `WHEN-TIMER-EXPIRED` to go and check your storage location every 10 seconds or so - you can then display a message to the user about the jobs, and kill the timer using `DELETE_TIMER`.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a single DBMS_JOB to call proc_submit_request. That way your form will only have to make one call; and the creation of all the other jobs will be done in a separate session.